# How to compare 2 files with common columns and then get the output file with columns from each file

Tags: awk

There are two input files; both are formatted as TSV.

```
File1: treated.bam.tsv 
File2: untreated.bam.tsv
```

Both files have the same fields, as listed below.
(I numbered then for presentation purposes) – each file has 23 fields.

```
1chrom           9mismatches_pp       17C_pp
2pos             10deletions          18T
3ref             11deletions_pp       19T_pp
4reads_all       12insertions         20G
5reads_pp        13insertions_pp      21G_pp
6matches         14A                  22N
7matches_pp      15A_pp               23N_pp
8mismatches      16C
```

If values in the 1st and 2nd columns (chrom, pos) are the same in both files, I want to extract some of the fields in the records, then make a new output file like this below. The output file has 15 fields, combining data from the two input files, as  below.

```
From file1:
  1chrom
  2pos
  3ref
  4reads_all
  8mismatches
  10deletions
  12insertions
  pct_file1 (the values from file1: (8mismatches+10deletions+12insertions)/4reads_all)
From file2:
  3ref
  4reads_all
  8mismatches
  10deletions
  12insertions
  pct_file2 (the values from file2: (8mismatches+10deletions+12insertions)/4reads_all)
-New values from extractions.
  pct_sub  (the values from pct_file1 - pct_file2: ((8mismatches+10deletions+12insertions)/4reads_all) - ((8mismatches+10deletions+12insertions)/4reads_all))
```

In the output file, the first eight columns come from File1, `treated.bam.tsv` (the 8th column is the value calculated with 8mismatches, 10deletions, 12insertions and 4reads_all from File1).

The rest of them come from File2, `untreated.bam.tsv`, and 13th column is also the value calculated with 8mismatches, 10deletions, 12insertions and 4reads_all from File2.

The last field, `pct_sub`, is calculated from the subtraction value with fields from File1 ((8mismatches+10deletions+12insertions)/4reads_all) and from File2 ((8mismatches+10deletions+12insertions)/4reads_all).

And how can I add new column names in output files, like `pct_file1`, `pct_file2`, `pct_sub`?

This is what I made for the above output file. (Input and output files have all same format: TSV.)

```
awk 'FNR==NR{array[$1,$2]=$0;next} { if ( $1 $2 in array ) print $1, $2, array[$3], array[$4], array[$8], array[$10], array[$12], (array[$8]+array[$10]+array[$12])/array[$4], $3, $4, $8, $10, $12, ($8+$10+$12)/$4, ((array[$8]+array[$10]+array[$12])/array[$4])-(($8+$10+$12)/$4) > "awkoutput.bam.tsv" }' treated.bam.tsv untreated.bam.tsv

(Actually, $1, $2 are not a problem from File1 or File2)
```

FILE1 (`treated`)

```
chrom pos ref reads_all reads_pp matches matches_pp mismatches mismatches_pp deletions deletions_pp insertions insertions_pp A A_pp C C_pp T T_pp G G_pp N N_pp

chrY 59363551 G 8 0 7 0 0 0 1 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0
chrY 59363552 G 7 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0
chrY 59363553 T 7 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0
chrY 59363554 G 7 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0
chrY 59363555 T 7 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0
```

FILE2 (`untreated`)

```
chrom pos ref reads_all reads_pp matches matches_pp mismatches mismatches_pp deletions deletions_pp insertions insertions_pp A A_pp C C_pp T T_pp G G_pp N N_pp
chrY 59363551 G 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
chrY 59363552 G 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
chrY 59363553 T 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
chrY 59363554 G 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
chrY 59363555 T 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

OUTPUT

```
chrom pos ref reads_all mismatches deletions insertions pct_file1 ref reads_all mismatches deletions insertions pct_file2 pct_sub
chrY 59363551 G 8 0 1 5 0.75 G 2 0 0 1 0.5 0.25
chrY 59363552 G 7 0 0 0 0 G 1 0 0 0 0 0
chrY 59363553 T 7 0 0 0 0 T 1 0 0 0 0 0
chrY 59363554 G 7 0 0 0 0 G 1 0 0 0 0 0
chrY 59363555 T 7 0 0 0 0 T 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `if ( $1 $2 in array )` doesn’t work;
   you have to do `if (($1,$2) in array)`.
2. You can’t use `array[$3]` and `array[$4]` like that. 
   Your array looks like

   ```
   array[chrY,59363551]=“chrY 59363551 G 8 0 7 0 0 0 1 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0”
   array[chrY,59363552]=“chrY 59363552 G 7 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0”
                ︙
   ```

   and when you say `array[$3]` and `array[$4]`,
   you’re referring to `array[G]` and `array[2]`, etc.,
   which do not exist.
3. The ability to specify `> "filename"` in `awk` code
   is a great feature when you want to write to multiple files. 
   It’s not so useful when you have only one output file —
   why don’t you just redirect the output from the `awk` command?
4. Long lines are bad. 
   Break long commands into short lines. 
   Reduce duplication by reusing variables.
5. Don’t use an array *called* `array`. 
   That’s like having a variable called `variable`,
   a file called `file`, a person called `Person`, etc. 
   Use descriptive names.

OK, that said,

```
awk 'FNR==NR {file1data[$1,$2]=$0; next}
        {       if (($1,$2) in file1data) {
                        # Save desired values from file2.
                        file2arg03=$3
                        file2arg04=$4
                        file2arg08=$8
                        file2arg10=$10
                        file2arg12=$12
                        pct_file2=($8+$10+$12)/$4
                        # Get data from file1.
                        $0=file1data[$1,$2]
                        pct_file1=($8+$10+$12)/$4
                        print $1, $2, $3, $4, $8, $10, $12, pct_file1, \
                                file2arg03, file2arg04, file2arg08, file2arg10, file2arg12, \
                                pct_file2, pct_file1-pct_file2
                } else printf "(%s,%s) in file2 but not file1.%s", $1, $2, ORS
        }' treated.bam.tsv untreated.bam.tsv > awkoutput.bam.tsv
```

Like your version, this saves the file1 data in an array
and then does all the work/output while it’s reading file2. 
Upon receiving a line from file2,
it saves the desired fields from that line into named variables
(we could also use another array, five elements long)
***and then*** it restores the data from the corresponding line in file1. 
By assigning the entire line to `$0`,
it causes `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, etc.,
to be restored to their original values.

Are you really having a problem writing a header line in the output? 
Try:

```
        {       if (FNR == 1) {
                        print "chrom pos ref reads_all mismatches deletions insertions pct_file1 …"
                } else if (($1,$2) in file1data ) {
                        file2arg03=$3
                              ︙
```

---

OK, here’s a version that’s closer in spirit to your attempt,
and that handles the header line:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {file1line[$1,$2]=$0; next}
        {       if (FNR == 1) {
                        print "chrom pos ref reads_all mismatches deletions insertions pct_file1 ref reads_all mismatches deletions insertions pct_file2 pct_sub …"
                } else if (($1,$2) in file1line ) {
                        # Get data from file1.
                        split(file1line[$1,$2], file1arg)
                        pct_file1=(file1arg[8]+file1arg[10]+file1arg[12])/file1arg[4]
                        pct_file2=($8+$10+$12)/$4
                        print $1, $2, file1arg[3], file1arg[4], file1arg[8], \
                                file1arg[10], file1arg[12], pct_file1, \
                                $3, $4, $8, $10, $12, pct_file2, pct_file1-pct_file2
                } else printf "(%s,%s) in file2 but not file1.%s", $1, $2, ORS
        }' treated.bam.tsv untreated.bam.tsv > awkoutput.bam.tsv
```

This retrieves the line from file1 (from `file1line`)
and passes it to `split` to break it down into its constituent 23 values,
which get stored in the array `file1arg`. 
Then it is able to use `file1arg[3]`, `file1arg[4]`, …,
the way you were using `array[$3]`, `array[$4]`, …

Answer (score 1):

Bioinformatics seems to be fun. If you are open to non-awk solutions, an easy job for [`miller`](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html):

```
mlr --itsv join -u -j chrom,pos --lp tr_ --rp untr_ -f treated.bam.tsv untreated.bam.tsv | # join data from treated and untreated files by fields chrom and pos
mlr put '$tr_pct=($tr_mismatches+$tr_deletions+$tr_insertions)/$tr_reads_all' | # calculate pct for treated data
mlr put '$untr_pct=($untr_mismatches+$untr_deletions+$untr_insertions)/$untr_reads_all' | # calculate pct for untreated data
mlr cut -o -f chrom,pos,tr_ref,tr_reads_all,tr_mismatches,tr_deletions,tr_insertions,tr_pct,untr_ref,untr_reads_all,untr_mismatches,untr_deletions,untr_insertions,untr_pct | # remove superfluous fields
mlr --otsv put '$pct_sub=$tr_pct-$untr_pct' # append pct subtraction field

chrom   pos tr_ref  tr_reads_all    tr_mismatches   tr_deletions    tr_insertions   tr_pct  untr_ref    untr_reads_all  untr_mismatches untr_deletions  untr_insertions untr_pct    pct_sub
chrY    59363551    G   8   0   1   5   0.750000    G   2   0   0   1   0.500000    0.250000
chrY    59363552    G   7   0   0   0   0   G   1   0   0   0   0   0
chrY    59363553    T   7   0   0   0   0   T   1   0   0   0   0   0
chrY    59363554    G   7   0   0   0   0   G   1   0   0   0   0   0
chrY    59363555    T   7   0   0   0   0   T   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

It looks scarier than it is. Really.